# Bundle exec rspec spec/static_pages_spec.rb cannot load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, bdd

I am trying to test a Rails app using Michael Hartl's tutorial, but I am getting following error after typing `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` (I am in the sample app directory)

static_pages_spec.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' `(SyntaxError)`
...age.should have_selector ('h1', :text => 'Sample App')

...                               ^

/Users/subalcharla/subal_rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...r ('h1', :text => 'Sample App')

/Users/subalcharla/subal_rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:14: `syntax error`, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
                        page.should have_selector ('title',

```
                                                       ^
```

/Users/subalcharla/subal_rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...ls Tutorial Sample App | Home")

/Users/subalcharla/subal_rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end

```
from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'

from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
```

from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'

from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'

from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'

from /Users/subalcharla/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'

```
My static_pages_spec.rb file is
```

require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

```
describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do  
                    visit '/static_pages/home'
                    page.should have_selector ('h1', :text => 'Sample App') 
    end 

    it "should have the right title" do
                    visit '/static_pages/home'
                    page.should have_selector ('title', 
                  :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")   
    end

end


describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Help')
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      visit '/static_pages/help' 
      page.should have_selector ('title',
        :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")

    end

end


describe "About page" do

  it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
        visit '/static_pages/about'
        page.should have_selector ('h1', :text => 'About Us')

      end 

  it "should have the right title" do
        visit '/static_pages/about'
        page.should have_selector ('title',
        :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
      end


end
```

end

I have checked my test file with the tutorial screencast and it looks identical. What could be causing the RED failing test to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leave spaces between a function and its opening parens, i.e.

```
page.should have_selector ('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
```

should be

```
page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
```